# Why does this curl command from firefox not download anything?

Tags: curl, firefox

I opened `https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli/master/README.rst` in Firefox, and copy the following curl command from Tools->Web Developer->Network:

```
curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli/master/README.rst' -H 'Host: raw.githubusercontent.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'If-None-Match: "6931c3b4d0e94743bb93a36ed8e8c3f5add12f9a"' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
```

When I run it in lxterminal, it doesn't download anything, even if I add `-O` to it. I was wondering why it doesn't download, and how I can make it download the file?

Thanks.

Comment: You should be aware that the *curl command* you get from Firefox *might* contain session cookies and that it can be used to impersonate you. Anyway, this one is safe because the github cookies are decoupled from the assets server.

Comment: Thanks. I was wondering what " impersonate" and "the github cookies are decoupled from the assets server" mean.

Comment: I meant that if you send a *curl command* to someone, they could use your session (eg. github account) as if they were you.

Comment: what do you suggest to do instead?

Comment: To not send the content of commands to anyone (or to redact cookies from commands).

Comment: Which part in a curl command may contain sensitive information? For example, in the one in my post?

Comment: @Tim Cookies header, but like Jules Lamur said, your example isn't vulnerable becase GitHub doesn't require your session for raw.githubusercontent.com. In any case, this isn't necessarily restricted to Cookies for other sites. They might chose to use other headers for sensitive info.

Comment: @JoL Can you give an example of leaking sensitive information using curl?

Comment: @Tim Copying as curl the github.com homepage while logged in. I'll repeat, just in case though, **don't share it**. You'd be giving control of your account to all viewers.

Comment: The *cliget* addon for Firefox: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/cliget/ constructs valid wget / curl command lines from web resources.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

When debugging `curl` issues, the `-v` option is often helpful. In this particular instance, you’re running afoul of the `If-None-Match` header, which tells the server that you already have the file matching “6931c3b4d0e94743bb93a36ed8e8c3f5add12f9a” and that you’re not interested in retrieving it again if it hasn’t changed. `-v` shows you this by indicating that the server responds with a 304 header:

```
< HTTP/1.1 304 Not Modified
```

To download your file, drop the header:

```
curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli/master/README.rst' -H 'Host: raw.githubusercontent.com' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Ubuntu; Linux x86_64; rv:60.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/60.0' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.5' --compressed -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0'
```

In this particular instance you’ll get the same result with

```
curl 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/andreafrancia/trash-cli/master/README.rst'
```